# I want to count number of each element in list using linq in c#

Tags: c#, linq, list, count, time-complexity

I write this code and its working correctly. Is there any better way to do this using `LINQ` to reduce time complexity.

```
List<int> list = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 7, 2, 2 };

var distinctList = list.Distinct();

var listWithCount = distinctList.Select(q=>new { num=q, count = list.Count(number=>number==q) });

foreach(var number in listWithCount)
{
    Console.WriteLine("num : " + number.num + "  count : " + number.count);
}
```

Comment: Worksing code is off-topic in SO, my friend, Perhaps you should post this in codereview.

Comment: you can try with GroupBy. I think it should be list.GroupBy(p => p).select(p => new { number = p.Key, count = p.Count()) ... or something like this.

Comment: thanx @AndreiNeagu

Answer (score 5):

You can use `GroupBy` together with `ToDictionary`:

```
List<int> list = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 7, 2, 2 };

Dictionary<int, int> counts = list.GroupBy(x => x)
                                  .ToDictionary(k => k.Key, v => v.Count());
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's the minimal change you need:

```
List<int> list = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 7, 2, 2 };

foreach (var number in list.GroupBy(x => x))
{
    Console.WriteLine("num : " + number.Key + "  count : " + number.Count());
}
```